# allowing desktop image to appear on div download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

is their any way that it would be possible to allow a user to upload his/ her images from desktop to an html2canvas? i would like for the user to upload images into a div convert to image after they are done, allong with the image they uploaded. i can convert the div to image but i cannot download the image to my desktop, with an outside image. i can only download the image to my desktop without outside images. this fist script is for downloading the div image to desktop

```js
var download = document.getElementById("download"),
  result = document.getElementById("previewImage");

function renderContent() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("firstshirt"), {
        allowTaint: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      result.appendChild(canvas);
        download.style.display = "inline"; download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL();
    });
}

function downloadImage() {
  
}

document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image").onclick = renderContent;
download.onclick = downloadImage
```

this second one is for the outside images to appear inside the div

```js
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("file1");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);

function previewImages() {
  var fileList = this.files;

  var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    var imgEl = $('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" width="75" height="85"/>');
    $('<div class="preview-area"/>').append('<a class="remove-img"> &times; </a>').append(imgEl).appendTo('.container5')
      .draggable();
    //^ change to this
    imgEl.load(function() {
      $(this).resizable();
    });
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
  }


}
$('.container').on('click', '.remove-img', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var parent = $(this).parents('.preview-area');
  parent.find('img').resizable('destroy');
  parent.draggable('destroy').remove();
});
```

will it be possible to make the outside image appear when i download the div into desktop?

Comment: What works and what doesn't work in the code shown? Does it produce errors? Problem description could use some editing to make it less circular and more concise and specific

Comment: im sorry for not explaining correctly. what doesnt work is that i cannot download the div as an image, when i upload my own image into the div i get a blank download.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue ? Try  `document.getElementById('yourcanvasid').toDataURL()` apply this as href of a link